# Python: Retrieve POST response from BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, post, response, basehttprequesthandler

I'm trying to retrieve the response after a POST request with Python using a BaseHTTPRequestHandler. To simplify the problem, I have two PHP files.

jquery_send.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendPOST() {
        url1 = "jquery_post.php";
        url2 = "http://localhost:9080";
        $.post(url1,
                {
                    name:'John',
                    email:'john@email.com'
                },
                function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
                    alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response + "\n\nStatus : " + status);
                });
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="sendPOST()">Send Data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery_post.php

```
<?php
    if($_POST["name"])
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        echo "Name: ". $name . ", email: ". $email; // Success Message
    }
?>
```

With *jquery_send.php*, I can send a POST request to *jquery_post.php* and retrieve the request successfully. Now, I want to get the same result sending the POST request to a Python BaseHTTPRequestHandler instead *jquery_post.php*. I'm using this Python code for testing:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):

        print("\n----- Request Start ----->\n")
        content_length = self.headers.getheaders('content-length')
        length = int(content_length[0]) if content_length else 0
        print(self.rfile.read(length))
        print("<----- Request End -----\n")

        self.wfile.write("Received!")
        self.send_response(200)


port = 9080
print('Listening on localhost:%s' % port)
server = HTTPServer(('', port), RequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

I can get the POST request, but I can't retrieve the response ("Received!") in *jquery_send.php*. What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

In short, I have this little Python code using a BaseHTTPRequestHandler to get a POST request and send a response.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print(self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length'])).decode("UTF-8"))

        content = "IT WORKS!"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(content))
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(content)

print "Listening on localhost:9080"
server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 9080), RequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

I can get the response with curl

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" localhost:9080
```

but I can't get it using ajax/jquery from a webpage (the server receives the POST request correcty, but the webpage doesn't retrieve the response). How can I do it?

Comment: Try flipping the lines 
self.wfile.write("Received!")
self.send_response(200) 
to

self.send_response(200)
self.wfile.write("Received!")

Comment: Flipping the lines didn't help... same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the CORS headers, as long as I was requesting from a different port (or something like that...). The problem is solved adding

```
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

to my response headers.